# prepare to focus first active element in a container

Tags: javascript, focus

I have a container on a page that should be prepared for focusing, i.e. when user pressed TAB button, the first active element in the container must be focused.

The simplest way I have thought so far is to find the last active element before the container, focus it and then blur it. Will it work? Is there a simpler way? How to find the last active element before the container (cross-browser)?

I do not want to change tabbed elements order, I just want to define the next element that will be selected.

Please use raw javascript, not frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I've used finally.
I just create fake empty link in the beginnig of the container and focus it. The link will be removed when it lose focus.

```
function prefocusElement(node)
{
  var fake = document.createElement("a");
  fake.setAttribute("href", "#");
  node.insertBefore(fake, node.firstChild);
  fake.focus();
  fake.addEventListener("blur", function(e) { node.removeChild(fake); }, false);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is looping over the container child nodes and try focusing them until you succeed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (!e)
        e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 9) {
      FocusFirst(document.getElementById("MyContainer"));
    } 
}

function FocusFirst(element) {
    try {
        element.focus();
    }
    catch(ex) {}

    if (document.activeElement == element)
        return true;

    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var oChild = element.childNodes[i];
        if (FocusFirst(oChild))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Sample HTML tested with: (IE, Chrome)

```
<div id="MyContainer">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div><span><input type="text" /></span></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

This will focus the first input box of the container upon tab click.

Comment: this approach should take into account more aspects: user can press SHIFT-TAB or focus another element with mouse

Comment: @whitered you mean if `SHIFT` is pressed while tab is pressed you don't want the `FocusFirst` to be called? Can't see any problem to focus with mouse, the code only hadles key press events..

Comment: yes, SHIFT+TAB, it expected to select the last active element before the container. And when user focuses an element with mouse and then presses TAB, the next element should be focused, not the first one. There is no problem to implement all this requirements, but it will cost a lot of code, while my solution is quite short.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the document and change focus onKeyUp.  Remove the listener once tab has been pressed:

```
document.onkeyup = onKeyEvent;

function onKeyEvent (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
       document.onkeyup = null;
       document.getElementById ('whatever').focus();
    } 
}
```